# Confused about DTOs when reading and editing. How to desing DTO for filling the form in VUEjs app?

Tags: api, vue.js, single-page-application, dto, endpoint

I am trying to develop an enterprise-level application. I have domain and application services. I have created my DTOs for multiple purposes separately. But confused about which way I should use them from the API viewpoint.

I have complex objects lets say,

```
public class Entity{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? ManufacturerId { get; set; }
   public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; } 
}

public class Manufacturer{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And I have corresponding DTOs designed with composition now. It was separated before.

```
public class EntityBaseDto{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EntityReadDto : EntityBaseDto{    
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

public class EntityWriteDto : EntityBaseDto{    
    public int? ManufacturerId { get; set; }
}
```

Now the question is,

I have a table which is filled with `List<EntityReadDto>` which is clear. Before, `EntityReadDto` also had the `ManufacturerDto` as fully included with id and text. Whenever I require to edit one of the entries from the table I was able to load the dropdown selected items or list of tags etc with the ids attached to the `Manufacturer` objects within ReadDtos. Now it is not possible. Since I wanted to simplify the codes I just converted them to strings that are read-only. Now I have created another endpoint to get an editable version of the record when needed. Ex: `EntityWriteDto` will be used to fill the form when the edit is clicked on a specific item. The manipulation will be carried on that DTO and sent with the PUT type request to edit the record.

I am not sure if this approach is ok for these cases. What is the best practice for this? I have many objects related to the entities from other tables. Is it ok to make a call to get an editable version from the backend or need to have it right away in a VUEjs app?

Comment: Personally I always do a GET of the data I want to edit before showing the edit form. That way you ensure you can get all the data needed for the edit, which will likely be more detailed than what is needed to display your list data. If you have lots of common data like list of countries, or other relation data needed to populate your dropdowns in the form you can consider using a store like Vuex to keep a local cache of it.

Comment: @Beyers thank you. I already have a store in which I am loading every application-wide applicable data like unique filter options, available table columns, some configuration data, etc. What I wanted to know is which type of approach would be the best practice for loading the edit form. Which you gave a decent explanation.